# How to import DateTimeFormatOptions in

Tags: typescript, datetime

I want to store a `DateTimeFormatOptions` for `date.toLocaleString()` to use in multiple places in my app. I defined it like:

```js
export const timeFormat = { month: 'numeric', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false, timeZoneName: 'short', time  Zone: 'UTC'}
```

And I get:

```js
Argument of type '{ month: string; day: string; hour: string; minute: string; hour12: boolean; timeZoneName: string; timeZone: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
  Types of property 'month' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"numeric" | "2-digit" | "short" | "long" | "narrow" | undefined'.
```

But I can't figure out import DateTimeFormatOptions. Eventually I just wrote a helper method that formats the date, but I still may need to import it because I may allow the user to change date preferences.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It's in the [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object. You won't need to import it. Just set the type to `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions`.

```
const timeFormat: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = { month: 'numeric', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false, timeZoneName: 'short', timeZone: 'UTC' }
```